# Moving to next textField inside an UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, tableview, becomefirstresponder

I have a tableView full of sub-classed textFields. Below is how i created them:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = kOddCellIdentifier;

    CustomCell01 *oddCell = (CustomCell01 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    oddCell.myTextfield.delegate=self;
    oddCell.myTextfield.tag = indexPath.row;
    oddCell.myTextfield.text=[[self.Page01dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"value"];
    bool editable = [[[self.Page01dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"editable"] boolValue];
    if (editable==true) {
        oddCell.myTextfield.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        oddCell.myTextfield.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [oddCell.myTextfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        oddCell.myTextfield.enabled=NO;
    }
    [oddCell.myTextfield addTarget:self action:@selector(updateField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

    return oddCell;
}
```

I do not know how to move to the next textfield when the user taps on the "Next" button. Normally i should make the next textfield the first responder however since all my textfields have the same name "myTextfield", i do not know how to do it. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out a solution by creating an array in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[nextTFarray addObject:oddCell.myTextfield];
```

and then:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    int i=[nextTFarray count];
    int x=textField.tag+1;
    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[nextTFarray objectAtIndex:x];
    if (x<i-1) {
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the name to something like `"myTextfield-<row>"`.  Then you can parse that and know what the prev/next fields are.  You are already setting `myTextfield.tag` to `indexPath.row` so you won't even have to parse the name.  You know the previous and next fields are `"myTextfield-<tag-1>"` and `"myTextfield-<tag+1>"`, respectively.

Comment: How am i going to refer to each textfield in - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField ? Could you please provide the actual code?